# Adding CSS styles

Tags: theming, 6, mimemail

I'm using the [Mimemail](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) module with the [Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module to theme an email newsletter, but it's not the least bit clear to me where I can store my styles so mimemail can then add them as inline styles to the various HTML tags. From my research I understand you can create a mail.css file where styles can be added or altered but that doesn't seem to be working for me. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't rely on stylesheets but rather create the inline code by hand and uncheck the option: Add stylesheets. If you find this difficult install [emogrifier module](http://drupal.org/project/emogrifier) (not sure but you might need to install htmlmail as well) that converts the stylesheet code to inline code.

I did myself an inline coding.

You might encounter an issue with weird characters breaking your lines in the email body, I am curious if this happens to you too, if so let me know. I think I have the fix for that too.

Answer (score 1):

The mail.css file should live in the root of your current theme. In fact if you're using an external stylesheet then you need to do this to avoid a WSOD as you may hit [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49697&edit=1) bug.

Comment: gmail ignores the mail.css file even if included. So emogrifier might be a better way to go, unless you include styles online.